# XAML how to bring an entire datatable into a popup window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

In the previous window I have a table. I can access specific data entries.

for example the code below takes the Description from the selected row, and places it inside of the textbox.

```
<TextBlock Text="Description" Style="{StaticResource tabTextBlock}"/>
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Vwr.Table.Tbl, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Description" SelectedValuePath="Description"
          SelectedIndex="{Binding Vwr.Table.SelectedRowIndex, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          Text="{Binding Vwr.Table.Vals[2].Val, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          IsEditable="True" Style="{StaticResource tabTextBox}" Height="54"/>
```

My question is:
How would I port the entire Table, so that it would be displayed in a DataGrid/Table format inside of an XAML Window?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data context is similar to the example you gave, this should work:

```xml
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Vwr.Table.Tbl}" />
```

By default, the `DataGrid` will automatically generate columns for each property in the item type.

Comment: for some reason this doesn't populate. just a thin empty box.

Comment: Is your data context set, and is your data accessible via `Vwr.Table.Tbl`?  Try adding the grid to the same window containing the `ComboBox`, just to see if it works.

Comment: I have, could it be because it's a popup window as opposed to an integrated one? It's also a usercontrol, instead of a window.

Comment: Actually , you're right. Taking the userControl sample code into the window sever's the ties. So it no longer populates. Do you know a way to carry context over from one window to another?

Comment: You would set the `DataContext` on the new window in the same way you're setting it on the old window.  Or you could manually copy it from the source.